# Multiple indexes over an in memory collection for faster search

Tags: c#, linq, lookup

I have a big in-memory collection of following simplified class:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I need to search for products based on different properties like UserName or CategoryId.
One way of searching would be using linq to objects like:

```
var userProducts = products.Where(x => x.UserName == "SomeValue")
```

This takes some processing when collection is too big and in my case it would be called hundreds of time each second.

What I came up with was to introduce a new collection that supports indexing over different properties:

```
public class FastCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private IList<T> _items;
    private IList<Expression<Func<T, object>>> _lookups;
    private Dictionary<string, ILookup<object, T>> _indexes;

    public FastCollection(IList<T> data)
    {
        _items = data;
        _lookups = new List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>();
        _indexes = new Dictionary<string, ILookup<object, T>>();
    }

    public void AddIndex(Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
    {
        _lookups.Add(property);
        _indexes.Add(property.ToString(), _items.ToLookup(property.Compile()));
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
        RebuildIndexes();
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        _items.Remove(item);
        RebuildIndexes();
    }

    public void RebuildIndexes()
    {
        if (_lookups.Count > 0)
        {
            _indexes = new Dictionary<string, ILookup<object, T>>();
            foreach (var lookup in _lookups)
            {
                _indexes.Add(lookup.ToString(), _items.ToLookup(lookup.Compile()));
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FindValue<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property, TProperty value)
    {
        var key = property.ToString();
        if(_indexes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return _indexes[key][value];
        }
        else
        {
            var c = property.Compile();
            return _items.Where(x => c(x).Equals(value));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

You can initialize the collection like this:

```
var fc = new FastCollection<Product>(products);
fc.AddIndex(x => x.Id);
fc.AddIndex(x => x.UserName);
fc.AddIndex(x => x.CategoryId);
```

And finally you can search the collection like this:

```
var userProducts = gc.FindValue(x => x.UserName, "SomeValue");
```

The fast collection makes a big difference when it comes to performance.

My question is if I'm doing it right? I have used delegates and expressions to make it as generic as possible but I have this feeling that there is room for improvement!

Comment: Im not entirely sure but doesnt .Where do some kind of hashing tables to speed up comparing? Possibly the hashing causes issues on massive collection.

Comment: @ppumkin No, `Where()` doesn't do any kind of hashing. Doing that wouldn't make sense, because it would have to create a separate hash table for each query.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `ToString()` to compare expressions for equality might work in simple cases, but:

- It requires you to always use the same parameter name, for example, it would consider `x => x.Id` and `product => product.Id` to be different expressions.
- Expressions with different meaning can produce the same string, for example `(int i) => (float)i` and `(int i) => (double)i` both produce `i => Convert(i)`. Because of this, it might make sense to ensure that the used expressions contain only property accesses and nothing else.

Instead you should [compare `Expression`s properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673246/41071).

---

It seems wasteful to me to rebuild all indexes after each change. If you change the collection often, consider changing only the relevant part of each index.

---

Fields that are set in the constructor and then never modified should be `readonly`.

---

```
IList<T> data
```

If you're on .Net 4.5, you could use `IReadOnlyList<T>` here.

---

```
if (_lookups.Count > 0)
```

This check is pretty much useless. It saves you from unnecessarily creating an empty dictionary, but doing that is very cheap, so I think shorter code should take the priority here.

---

You could replace the whole `RebuildIndexes()` method with a single `ToDictionary()`:

```
_indexes = _lookups.ToDictionary(
    lookup => lookup.ToString(), lookup => _items.ToLookup(lookup.Compile()));
```

---

```
c(x).Equals(value)
```

This won't work correctly when `c(x)` returns `null`. You should probably use `object.Equals(c(x), value)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

When I test your collection against a list using `Where`.  `Where` out performs your collection by a large factor.  For instance 1,000 queries, with each one returning 1,000 records from a collection with 1,000,000 random elements takes less than 1 ms, whereas FindValue takes about 15 ms.

EDIT:

Ok with iterating the FastCollection does individual searches better.

Did some more thinking on it.  One of the reasons it seems so blindingly fast, is you're hiding the extra time and resources building a lookup table for each property you want to search by.

One thing to consider is keeping your data in a DataTable instead of a list and use the Select method.  This allows for very fast searches with times that are comparable to your class, when you factor in the extra time building the lookup table.  However now it's in a format ready made for display in a DataGridView, or exporting to an xml file.  One caveat is that the data is returned as a collection of DataRow, which might be a bother depending on what you intend for the data.

Comment: That's weird, my timings show agree with your that iterating `FindValue` takes 15 ms, but on my computer, iterating `Where()` takes 10 ms. It's still faster, but the difference is not that big.

Comment: @svick  I added my test code in case my test was incomplete.

Comment: `var temp = products.Where(x => x.UserName == searchindexes[i]);` That's your problem right there, you call `Where()`, but you never iterate the result. But since `Where()` is lazy, that doesn't do almost anything, so your comparison is not fair. Instead, you should compare iterating over the results of `Where()` with iterating results of `FindValue()`.

Comment: @svick is right. Until you don't iterate over the result the query is not executed. If you append ToList() to the end of Where and FindValue statements it will execute the queries and the results would be accurate. I did run above test and FindValue is extremely faster.

Comment: @Atashbahar added some more thoughts for you to consider.

Comment: @tinstaafl: I agree that creating the fast collection is a bit heavy and it's more suitable for collections that won't be changed that often. Compared to DataTable this is a strongly typed collection which might be used for purposes other than displaying in a tabular format.

Comment: Along with DataTable to hold the data, consider using [DataView class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview) per secondary index. As for having a "strongly typed collection" as mentioned by @Atashbahar, this is possible using xsd.exe: [Generating Strongly Typed DataSets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/generating-strongly-typed-datasets). Not sure if anyone has written code to use reflection to generate the strongly typed classes from a .Net class - that would make this more practical for general .Net coding.

Comment: ... I mean given a class like OP's `Product`, and a list of fields to build indices on, it should be possible to *generate* something like his `FastCollection`, built on strongly-typed DataTable and associated DataViews. So coder doesn't have to hand-write the xsd file. The benefit is that these classes handle modifying the internal indices as you change rows.

Answer (score 3):

The FastCollection contains an additional list and a dictionary of lists, so it's memory consumption overhead might become an issue.

I would suggest that you look into representing your data structure (Product) in a data structure which is more optimal for searching than a list. If you into tree-structures or balanced tree structures, you will see that searching cost O(log n), where n is the number of elements in the tree.

You can easily build the tree structure with a custom compare function, and thereby having a very fast generic searchable structure.

Well, just an idea, which you might consider overkill :)

Comment: How does this help OP "search for products based on different properties"? The data needs to be in a collection that can be looked up O(1) by some master key, so that each property can be represented by an additional collection that provides that master key. O(log n) lookup is moving in the wrong direction, performance-wise.